# Circleci : How to run jobs serially in circle ci without depending on success only

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

I want to run two jobs sequentially in a circleci workflow . However I want the second one to run regardless of the outcome of the first one. Right now it looke to me like I only have two options either run it in parallel which I do not want or have them run serially but if the first one fails the rest do not execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Why can't you run parallel? If there's something one job needs from the other, that's what sequential is for.

I'd either settle for the sequential as it is now, or depending on your specific circumstances (which I'm not aware of), you may be able to do 3 jobs. One base job that splits into two parallel.